# How do I correctly phrase the sentence "X myself, I do/don't have a problem with Y"?

Tags: complex-sentences

In this sentence, X and Y are popularly seen as contradicting. 
For example,

1.Even though I'm a vegetarian, I don't have a problem with people killing animals for food.

2.Even though I'm American, I have a problem with Americans I meet abroad.

Can i say "A vegetarian myself, I (still?) don't have a problem with people killing for meat"? I know I've heard this type of expression many times.

Comment: If you hear that type of expression (the "Vegetarian myself" example) many times, you either spend a lot of time in the company of poets and other rarefied literary types, or you know lots of non-native speakers. It's not idiomatic to use such pared down syntax in normal conversation.

Comment: You could say "**I'm a** vegetarian myself, **but** I don't have ...".  You could not properly commence with just "Vegetarian myself, ...".  It's possible that someone saying "I'm a vegetarian myself, ..." might 'swallow' the words "I'm a" such that you didn't hear them properly.

Comment: I think what I'm going for is more like "being a vegetarian myself, i...."

Comment: "Vegetarian" can be either a noun or an adjective; as a noun, it would be correct and idiomatic to use either of the forms @TrevorD or insanity suggest. As an adjective, the form you propose would be correct, but somewhat unusual/poetic. A clearer example might be something like: "Devastated myself, I could not bear to be around happy people." Again, that would be technically correct, but sounds stilted to my (AmE) ear.

Comment: The type of sentence you've asked about includes two 'contrasting' thoughts/positions. It therefore needs some word or phrase suitable for 'joining' the two 'contrasting' positions. (Sorry, I don't know the technical terminology.)  In your example sentences, that phrase is "even though"; in my example, it's "but"; it could alternatively be "although". But, personally, I do not feel that your suggestion of "*being* a vegetarian myself, ..." would work because the word "being" implies that 2 *complementary* things are being joined rather than 2 *contrasting* things.

Comment: @TrevorD May be if i added the negative in the 2nd part of the sentence? "(Being) a vegetarian myself, I STILL do no have a problem with..."

Comment: @nedibes Yes, thats the sentence construction i was talking about - "Devastated myself, I could not bear to be around happy people." How would i phrase it if I wanted to say I COULD be around happy people? TrevorD raises a valid concern.

Comment: If it's clearly a contrast, you could use "nevertheless" or "still" in the middle, or "although" or "while" at the start (like your first example): *Devastated myself, I nevertheless wanted to hear your good news*. If you google "myself I nevertheless" (as a phrase, including the quotation marks) you should see some examples that do set up an opposition, such as this tweet: https://twitter.com/decentfilms/status/627088706743238656

Comment: @nedibes Thank you! If there's any way you could form an answer out of your comments, I'll accept it.

Comment: This usage is grammatical, and makes sense (so goes one better, other than as a teaching instrument, than Chomsky's 'Colorless ...'). But as FF says, it would be considered odd to weird in casual conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up a contrast using this structure, use an introductory word like "although" or "while" at the start, or else a word like "nonetheless" or "still" in the middle.

(Note that in your particular example, you would need to treat "vegetarian" as a noun rather than an adjective, because as an adjective 'vegetarian' generally refers to a food that doesn't contain meat rather than people who don't eat meat: *A vegetarian* eats *vegetarian* meals.)

So you would say something like:

> **Though** *a* vegetarian myself, I don't have a problem with others eating
>   meat.

or

> *A* vegetarian myself, I **still** don't have a problem with others eating meat.

For 'pure' adjectives, you can omit the article:

> Tone-deaf myself, I **nevertheless** enjoy singing in the choir.

Some examples from around the web:

> "**Though I am not continent myself, I nevertheless sincerely approve**
>   the continency of the Capuchins, and other religious orders, and am
>   pleased with their way of living." —[Michel de Montaigne, *The Essays
>   of Michael de Montaigne*, Volume 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=vrVNAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA276&ots=aeeLVU4bNn&dq=%22myself%20i%20nevertheless%22&pg=PA276#v=onepage&q=%22myself%20i%20nevertheless%22&f=false), 1811
>
> "**A little groggy myself, I nonetheless recognize** that I have just
>   taken part in a ceremony that goes back in history to the time before
>   my own religion came to birth." —[Harvey Cox, *Common Prayers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Khega4cbU5QC&lpg=PA132&ots=Xf3usM3nFb&dq=%22myself%20i%20nonetheless%22&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q=%22myself%20i%20nonetheless%22&f=false),
>   2002
>
> "**A historian myself, I nevertheless found** her analysis accessible,
>   well-informed in terms of primary documentation, thought-provoking,
>   and frequently convincing." —[Catherine A. Mooney, in a review
>   article](http://josotl.indiana.edu/index.php/tmr/article/view/15616/21734), 2004
>
> "**Not a fan of the show myself, I nevertheless thought** that Katey Sagal
>   was way too good to be a part of that sitcom." —[Lynette McDonald,
>   "Does Katey Sagal Have Insider Information on How 'Sons of Anarchy'
>   Will End? *Inquisitr*](http://www.inquisitr.com/1208837/does-katey-sagal-have-insider-information-on-how-sons-of-anarchy-will-end/), 2014
>
> "He asked me “How are you at handling criticism?” **Unsure myself, I
>   nevertheless felt confident enough** to say that “I’m ok at it.”" —[Eric
>   Thomas Weber, transcript of "Philosophy Bakes Bread" podcast](http://philosophybakesbread.com/2015/07/31/ep3-transcript-coping-with-uncertainty/), 2015
>
> "**As a Female Myself, I Still Don't Know Why** Y'all Shave and Redraw"
>   —[Tweet?](http://9gag.com/gag/a3j3wo8/as-a-female-myself-i-still-don-t-know-why-y-all-shave-and-redraw)

The 1811 and 2014 examples are actually probably the way this construction appears most often:

> (Even though I am) **not** (an) X myself, I (nevertheless)...

So you might say:

> Though not a meat-eater myself, I don't have a problem with
>   people killing animals for food.

---

As an aside, I take it that by "continent" de Montaigne meant *abstaining from various bodily pleasures* rather than *in control of his bodily functions*. Though the more modern definition would certainly give him a reason to be pleased with the Capuchins' way of living.